# Does Alipay support subscriptions

Tags: payment-processing, recurring-billing, subscriptions, alipay

I need to integrate subscription billing using alipay. Does Alipay support subscriptions? . I got a sample project for 'overseas auto debit service'. Is this same like subscritions in paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in comparison to CloudPayments, it is not exactly the same, as I understood.

According to https://global.alipay.com/service/debit/3 the process consists of two steps:

1. Customer agreement signing
2. Invoking payment process by merchant with reference to the agreement

It gives an opportunity to conduct withholding payment without repeated user confirmation. I'm not aware of paypal's features, but the fact is that burden of recurrent payment implementation falls on the shoulders of merchant system developer.

Alipay will not automatically withdraw money from user's balance.

Answer (score 0):

Found some Chinese docs about recurring billing on the open platform of AliPay.com for Chinese payments but I'm not sure if it applies to international payments:

https://opendocs.alipay.com/mini/006srl